# Solving $x_1 + \dots + x_n = m$ with general (i.e. not specific to a variable) restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

The number of non-negative integer solutions to

$$x_1 + \dots + x_n = m$$

is extremely well known to be ${m + n - 1 \choose m}$. It is also not difficult to solve if we require, say, $x_1 \geq 5$: we simply change $x_1 \mapsto x_1' + 5$, so $x_1' \geq 0$ and the answer is just ${m + n - 6 \choose m - 5}$.

However, how can we solve this when we require *some* variable to be larger than $k$? For example, how many solutions are there to

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 7$$

where *some* $x_i \geq 3$?

I am also interested in the general question of how many solutions are there to the original question where we require $c_i$ of the variables to be at least $i$, such that

$$\sum_{i} c_i \leq n, \sum_{i} i c_i \leq m.$$

(The above case is then a special case with $n = 4, m = 7,$ and $c_3 = 1, c_i = 0$ otherwise).

Further generalizations can be made where we specify some variables must also be less than or equal to some number (which, in conjunction with $\geq$ we can also specify that some variables *equal* some number). I do not expect this question to be answered since it's likely to be very involved, however I am welcome to be surprised.

Comment: Can this approach work in $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 7$ where some $x_i \geq 3$: Find all solutions with no constraints and find those in which all are < 3 and subtract this number from the total. For more than one constraint, perhaps a messy inclusion exclusion may get the answer.